# Creating multiple indexes using script

Tags: mongodb

How do I create a multiple indexes using a script/file so that I can run it in the shell and create all the indexes in one action?

The info is listed here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Do I create a javascript file (.js) and just list all the `ensureIndex`es one after another like:

```
db.data1.ensureIndex(..)
db.data2.ensureIndex(..)
db.data3.ensureIndex(..)
db.data4.ensureIndex(..)
```

Is this syntactically correct? Is this going to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are right.

You write a js function in a file

```
a = {}
a.b = function(){
  db.coll.createIndex(<options>);
  // do all other things
}
a.c = function(){
  // something else
}
```

then load js

```
load("jsfile.js")
```

then execute your function `a.b();`

What problems do you have with your code? What do you mean by compile?

Comment: +1 on the js function.
Also, for anyone coming across this now - the ensureIndex() collection method is deprecated (since vs. 3.0.0). It is now an alias for the newer createIndex() method, which essentially supports the same call signature.